# Select 2 multiple tags overflows wrapper element

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I have a select 2 multiple select element which shows tags for selected items. But as I see tags overflow the wrapper element and it looks really bad. It does not make any sense cause there is no css rule for height of related element. Everything should be responsible. Does anybody know what could be the problem?
Here is a screenshot

[image]

and here is a screenshot of wrapper element

[image]